# split each cell in dataframe (pandas/python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe consisting of many rows and columns containing binary data like '0|1', '0|0','1|1','1|0'  which i would like to split either in 2 dataframes, and/or expand so that this (both are useful to me):

```
        a   b   c   d
rowa    1|0 0|1 0|1 1|0
rowb    0|1 0|0 0|0 0|1
rowc    0|1 1|0 1|0 0|1
```

becomes

```
        a   b   c   d
rowa1   1   0   0   1
rowa2   0   1   1   0
rowb1   0   0   0   0
rowb2   1   0   0   1
rowc1   0   1   1   0
rowc2   1   0   0   1
```

and/or

```
    df1:    a   b   c   d
    rowa    1   0   0   1
    rowb    0   0   0   0
    rowc    0   1   1   0


    df2:    a   b   c   d
    rowa    0   1   1   0
    rowb    1   0   0   1
    rowc    1   0   0   1
```

currently i'm trying to do something like the following, but believe this is not very effective, any guidance would be helpful.

```
Atmp_dict=defaultdict(list)
Btmp_dict=defaultdict(list)

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    for columnname in list(df.columns.values):
        Atmp_dict[columnname].append(row[columnname].split('|')[0])
        Btmp_dict[columnname].append(row[columnname].split('|')[1])
```

Comment: Is your data coming from a file?

Comment: yes, a file that i loaded  as a pandas dataframe

Comment: can you add a snippet of how the input file looks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty compact, but it seems like there should be an even easier and more compact way.

```
df1 = df.applymap( lambda x: str(x)[0] ) 
df2 = df.applymap( lambda x: str(x)[2] )
```

Or loop over the columns as in the other answers.  I don't think it matters.  Note that because the question specified binary data, it is OK (and simpler) to just do `str[0]` and `str[2]` rather than using `split` or `extract`.

Or you could do this, which seems almost silly, but there's nothing actually wrong with it and it is fairly compact.

```
df1 = df.stack().str[0].unstack()
df2 = df.stack().str[2].unstack()
```

`stack` just converts it to a series so you can use `str` and then `unstack` converts it back to a dataframe.

Comment: For very large data sets, any thoughts on performance using a built-in pandas function like .str.extract() vs using a python-defined lambda? I'm not sure if extract is implemented as a C extension

Comment: @drootang  I'm not sure in this case, you could use `%timeit` in ipython to compare.  Generally speaking, the advantage of pandas is crunching numbers not strings, so it might not matter too much.  But generally speaking, `apply/lambda` will be slower than using built in pandas methods.

Comment: @drootang OK I quickly tested your 2 ways and my 2 ways on 1000 rows of data.  From fastest to slowest:  split (3.28ms), applymap (3.91ms), stack (4.25ms), extract (9.71ms).

Comment: Interesting and surprising! If split is fastest, explicitly enumerating on the columns, I suspect your suggestion in comments to just use df[col].str[0] and df[col].str[1] is probably the champion here.

Answer (score 2):

user2734178 is close, but his or her answer has some issues. Here is a slight variation that works

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

# df is your original DataFrame
for col in df.columns:
    df1[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x.split('|')[0])
    df2[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x.split('|')[1])
```

Here is another option that is slightly more elegant. Replace the loop with:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df1[col] = df[col].str.extract("(\d)\|")
    df2[col] = df[col].str.extract("\|(\d)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like all of your values are strings, you can use the `.str` accessor to split up everything using the pipe as your delimiter, comme ca,

```python
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

#df is defined as in your first example
for col in df.columns:
    df1[col] = df[col].str[0]
    df2[col] = df[col].str[-1]
```

You'll then probably want to recast your `df1` and `df2` as `int` columns using `astype(int)`.

Comment: Your answer is not quite right, but you could fix it with `str[0]` instead of `str.split('|')[0]`  FYI, I didn't downvote but you might want to either fix or delete